# Glide.js - how to style image on next/prev slide

Tags: jquery, slider

i am using Glide.js, i want to style slider like that:
i want to see other elements not only active/current, so i turned of css:overflow:hidden, next i want to add to next and prev element blur or opacity. I know that glide.js have function next()/prev(), but i don't know how to set the attribute style to next/prev element i tried:

```
slide.next().find("img").attr("style","opacity:0.5");
```

with result: cannot recognize find.
so i tried:

```
slide.next(function(){ $(this).find("img").attr("style","opacity:0.5")});
```

with no bugs but also with no effect.
Can someone please explain me how it shoud works, maybe i don't understand what next()/prev() do and it shoud look way different. Thanks for response.

Answer (score 0):

also now i think that better idea is to set to all elements opacity and only to current element remove it or set opacity:1; and i tried this way as well, but still something is wrong, and i dont know what.
i tried:

```
$("#menuSlider .slider-nav").children().change(function(){
    var slide = glide.current();
    var Img = $('#galeria li.slide:nth-child(' + slide + ')').find("img");
    Img.attr("style","opacity:1");
    });
```

but i think the first line is wrong, because if i leave only what is inside the function it works (but only for first element because program don't see the change of slide)

how it shoud like properly?

Comment: It's been long but were you able to achieve this?